# what is the best way to get most accurate location lat long in android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location

I have to send current lat,long to webservice parameter ,On the basis of that ,i get response from server sorted by my current location.

The problem is that i have to send most accurate location .so I use GPS provider,but if i use GPS in indoor loation than sometime it takes so much time to get location and it shows loader for unlimited time.

What is the best way to get most accurate location in minimum time ?
 I will appreciate your answer for above query.

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: Yes, being indoor slows down connections to GPS satellites 22k miles above your head... Use both location providers and always use the best one. Full example in Google's documentation (above).

Comment: well GPS always gives most accurate location than other methods, you can try getting location using `network provider` also.

Comment: After developing several GPS-based apps and running into the same issues you're referring to, I've (personally) found Google Play Services' API to be the most reliable and most accurate whether it's indoors or outdoors, and it's far easier to integrate and manage than handling the providers manually. You may want to look into the Play Services if that's an option for you, as it was the best decision I made in regards to location-based stuff: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html and http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: @Guardanis: thanks for your answer. does Fused location provider gives location by cellular network ie 3g or 4g ,if wifi is off?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, but correct me if I'm wrong